# É correto retornar um endereço de memória em função?

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, memória

Solicitaram-me projetar uma função que fosse chamada, abrisse um arquivo .txt e retornasse o ponteiro deste arquivo, ou seja, retornasse um endereço de memória. Entretanto pelo que eu sei a memória é alocada apenas temporariamente para funções, ou seja, após o término da execução da função a memória está livre para ser usada por outra parte do programa.

Penso que o mais correto seria declarar o ponteiro para arquivo numa função principal (`main`) e então enviar o ponteiro como parâmetro para uma função que abrisse o arquivo e o "apontasse" para o endereço de memória que foi enviado. Estou correto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Há um conceito errado no seu pensamento, talvez lhe falte melhor entendimento sobre [*stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Se a informação estiver no *stack* realmente você não pode confiar que ela estará lá quando a função terminar, mas é um pouco mais raro você criar um ponteiro para a pilha.

Mas se for alocado no *heap*, você pode retornar um ponteiro para esta área alocada sem problemas. A área continua disponível mesmo quando a função terminar. Este é a principal razão para usar o *heap*.

Você até está correto em seu pensando do ponto de vista de organização do código. O mais correto é a função que precisa de uma informação alocar a memória necessária para o objeto, passar isto para a função que vai preencher este objeto e depois quando voltar para ela liberar esta memória.

Nada impede que você aloque em uma função que vai preencher e retorne, mas fica assimétrico, porque ela é responsável por alocar e não faz a liberação (nem poderia neste caso), isto dá margem a erros. Funções bem construídas exigem que os consumidores dela entreguem a memória já alocada. Mesmo que precise de uma realocação dentro dela, isto é menos problemático. Curiosamente isso é basicamente a tão propalada injeção de dependência.

Então do ponto de vista técnico pode fazer como te pediram, mas qualquer bom programador faria do jeito que você está pensando, você está correto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).