# Qual a diferença entre Casse obj; e Classe* obj = new Classe(); em C++?

Tags: c, c++, orientação-a-objetos

Eu sei que utilizando Classe obj; estou armazenando obj na Stack e com Classe* obj = new Classe(); estou armazenando na Heap. Mas, na prática, qual a diferença?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57006/101 ajuda também. Na prática a diferença já está na pergunta, isso não é teoria.

Comment: Mas, qual a diferença prática de alocar na Stack ou na Heap? Quando eu vou querer alocar na heap, se eu consigo passar o endereço do que tá na stack e alterar por referencia?

Comment: Se acompanhar todos os *links* que tem na perguntas e na resposta lá verá tudo isso. Está tudo respondido já. veja também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83293/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101